# PayPalSDK throwing 401(Unauthorized access) when giving valid credentials

Tags: .net, paypal

I downloaded the PayPal examples directly from their website for .NET https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/master/Samples. The GitHub link comes from PayPal, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/code-samples/.

I opened PayPal.SDK.Samples.VS2013 and ran it. It works. I changed the Client ID and secret to my own in web.config and changed the mode to live:

```
  <add name="mode" value="live"/>
  <add name="clientId" value="xxx"/>
  <add name="clientSecret" value="yyy​"/>
```

It works. Now, I give it the Client ID and secret for my account i'm going to be using in production and guess what, it fails! I get the following error:

```
        Error thrown from SDK as type PayPal.IdentityException.
        {
         "error": "invalid_client",
         "error_description": "Invalid client credentials"
         }
```

I have tripled checked that i'm using the live PayPal API credentials, the client id and secret. I made absolutely no code changes, just the aforementioned web.config changes. Any idea as to why I'm getting this? Thanks for any and all help

Comment: This is Jason with PayPal. Does this error get thrown during the initial call to authenticate with PayPal?  Can you verify the production account credentials are being correctly?  You may need to use another program like Fiddler as it looks like the authentication call details aren't making it into the logfile (I'll get this fixed in the next SDK release).  If the client ID and secret are being sent correctly, then you may need to contact [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/).

Comment: Hi Jason, PayPal solved the problem. I had some extraneous characters at the end of my secret that would only show up in VIM text editor. I removed them and it works fine. Thanks for responding to my question